# Write a total, terminating Haskell function given a type

Tags: haskell, types

Given a type, determine if you can write a total, terminating Haskell function.

For a type like `Int -> Int`, we know that the finite-precision integer type Int covers at least the range `[-2^29, 2^29-1]` so there are finitely many possible mappings we can have from Int to Int so we can write a total, terminating function.

For example, given the following type: `(a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)`, how can I determine if we can write a total terminating function for using that type as the function signature? Or this type `(a -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)`.

Would greatly appreciate guidance through this problem! This is a homework question so I am only seeking guidance.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that, when dealing with all the types GHC supports (including GADTs), determining if a given type is inhabited by some total term is undecidable, in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given:

```
(a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)
```

We know that this is *not necessarily partial* by the Curry–Howard correspondence—interpreting `->` as logical implication, product types as AND, and sum types as OR—we find it forms a tautology. But in order to find an implementation and know that it *is total*, we need to actually find the proof:

```
   (a → b) → (b → c) → a → c
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- currying
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   (a → b) ∧ (b → c) → a → c
--           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- currying
--           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   (a → b) ∧ (b → c) ∧ a → c
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- commutativity of AND
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   (b → c) ∧ (a → b) ∧ a → c
--           ~~~~~~~~~~~
-- modus ponens
--           ~
   (b → c) ∧ b → c
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~
-- modus ponens
-- ~
   c → c
-- ~~~~~
-- reflexivity of implication
-- ~
   1
```

(This is a *hypothetical syllogism*.)

We can use this proof to arrive at an implementation—skipping the currying steps here, and with *modus ponens* corresponding to function application:

```
f ab bc a = bc (ab a)
```

The argument is similar for `(a -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)` interpreting `(a, b)` as `a ∧ b` (logical AND).

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer:

For finite data types, such as `Int` you mention, or `Bool` (all the Bounded could be included I guess). Then yes, you can provide a complete function:

if you have the time to cover all the cases for `Int`:

```
negative :: Int -> Int
negative 0 = 0
negative 1 = -1
negative 2 = -2
negative 3 = -3
...............
...............
negative -1 = 1
negative -2 = 2
...
...
...
```

until you cover all the cases... It's just an example.

With `Bool` is a little more obvious you can:

```
negative :: Bool -> Bool
negative False = True
negative True  = False
```

but, for functions, that takes functions, they are called [Uncontable set](http://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set), so you can provide all the posible combination of functions, so it will never ends, you will always find another "level" of function of functions, it's a "bigger infinite" than Nats set.

The main question:

> How to determine if one can write a total, terminating Haskell function given a type?

`(a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)` and `(a -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)` **maybe** you can provide **one**.

But what about:

```
(a -> b -> c -> d -> e) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c) -> (d -> e)
```

I just can say for sure that you cannot guarantee that you will find at least one **for all** the combinations of all the types **at least one**. But how to is very well answered by @Jon Purdy